# Add Email To Firebase account linked with phone Number

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am login account in flutter using phoneNumber Authentciation , and adding email to firebase account . I tried `Firebase.instance.currentuser.updateEmail(string email)` as well as

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
        email: emailController.text.trim(),
        actionCodeSettings: ActionCodeSettings(
            url:
                "https://example.page.link/cYk9",
            androidPackageName:
                AppPackage.package,
            iOSBundleId: "com.example.app",
            handleCodeInApp: true,
            androidMinimumVersion: "16",
            androidInstallApp: true),
      )
      .catchError((onError) => print(
          'Error sending email verification $onError'))
      .then((value) => print(
          'Successfully sent email verification'));
} catch (error) {
  print(error);
}
```

None of the process is working and throwing and error  like  this

> external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);

Please Guide me to fix this issue.